# Virtual CD added to Linux virtual box not showing up

Tags: linux

I added a new disk to my Linux OS running on Orace Virtual Box.As you can see it is a secondary IDE device:

[image]

Now, I wanted to created a partition and mount this drive and since this is a second IDE device I should be able to locate it in `/dev/hdb`

[image]

However, when I try to run the fdisk it says that the drive cannot be opened:

[image]

I am a new Linux user. Can someone give me some directions please?

Comment: why do you expect a nonexistent CD to be mountable?

Comment: Even if you inserted a CDROM, I doubt you could partition it. CDROMs are read-only devices, be it on Linux or other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily a VirtualBox usage problem, not a Linux problem.

Your virtual machine now has the initial virtual disk, and two virtual CD/DVD drives. Neither of those virtual CD/DVD drives have any virtual CDs (= ISO images) inserted.

Also, if your Linux distribution uses a modern libata-based driver for IDE, the device names might actually be `/dev/sda` for the first disk and `/dev/sdb` for the second one, instead of `/dev/hd*` names used by the old IDE subsystem. You can probably use the `lsblk` command to easily see what storage devices the Linux system actually has detected.

You might want to delete the extra virtual CD/DVD drive, then try and add a virtual HDD instead. When you do that, VirtualBox will want to know what the size of the virtual HDD should be, how should the image file for it be named on the host system, and what virtual disk image format should be used for it (the default .vdi should be fine). The disk image file will initially be small, but will grow as more data is written to the virtual disk, until the size corresponding the specified virtual HDD size has been reached.